# LDAP-based Apache auth (mod_ldap + mod_authnz_ldap) using own CA for SSL/TLS

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap, certificate, certificate-authority, mod-auth-ldap

**SOLVED: Turned out problem was caused by forgotten legacy `LDAPTrustedGlobalCert` directives in various config files, using old certificate for the same FQDN**

tl;dr: We uses a self-signed CA and we never had to use directives that disable certificates verification: how to make Apache trust our self-signed CA for `mod_ldap`?

I am trying to configure my Apache web server for an HTTP authentication using an LDAP directory as user base.

Everything works fine in non-encrypted mode but fails with a HTTP 500 error code with SSL or STARTTLS.

Here is my Apache configuration:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "WebServer"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on

# Plain:
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.example.com/dc=example,dc=local?uid?sub?(objectClass=person)"

# SSL:
LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CA_BASE64 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://ldap.example.com:636/dc=example,dc=local?uid?sub?(objectClass=person)" SSL

# StartTLS
LDAPTrustedGlobalCert CA_BASE64 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
LDAPTrustedMode TLS
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.example.com/dc=example,dc=local?uid?sub?(objectClass=person)"

AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=webserver.example.com,ou=Apps,dc=example,dc=local"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "secret"
```

`/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is a concatenation of multiple CA certificates (generated by *ca-certificates* Debian package). I've tried by pointing `LDAPTrustedGlobalCert` to either the rootCA or the subCA having signed the ldap.example.com certificates: same issue.

*error.log* says:

```
# TLS:
auth_ldap authenticate: user john-doe authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_start_tls_s() failed][Connect error]

# SSL:
auth_ldap authenticate: user john-doe authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Can't contact LDAP server]
```

We are using a PKI with a self-managed root CA (self-signed) and several sub-CA that signs certificates for web and LDAP servers.
By adding the sub-CA PEM file on our servers and configuring *ca-certificates* Debian package and *ldap.conf* (for `TLS_CACERT`), the LDAP can be successfully accessed via plain non-encrypted (port 389), StartTLS (port 389) and SSL (port 636) for Linux PAM (*libnss-ldapd* Debian package) and LDAP browser softwares.

How can I tell Apache to check received certificates and trust my rootCA?

**Edit to answers @shane-madden ideas**

- Works if using `LDAPVerifyServerCert Off`.
- `openssl s_client -connect ldap.example.com:636 -showcerts` returns the following:

  ```
  CONNECTED(00000003)
  depth=3 CN = ExampleRootCa, O = Example, C = FR
  verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
  verify return:0
  ---
  Certificate chain
   0 s:/CN=ldap.example.com/O=Example/C=FR
     i:/CN=ExampleSrvCa/O=Example/C=FR
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIGcDCCBF
  ...
  iyrFEYDcs=
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   1 s:/CN=ExampleSrvCa/O=Example/C=FR
     i:/CN=ExampleMainCa/O=Example/C=FR
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIF2DCCA8
  ...
  GrskgqnaEg
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   2 s:/CN=ExampleMainCa/O=Example/C=FR
     i:/CN=ExampleRootCa/O=Example/C=FR
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIF1TCCA7
  ...
  RozDAcZnph
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   3 s:/CN=ExampleRootCa/O=Example/C=FR
     i:/CN=ExampleRootCa/O=Example/C=FR
  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIFWzCCA0
  ...
  RY5xwHgA==
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  ---
  Server certificate
  subject=/CN=ldap.example.com/O=Example/C=FR
  issuer=/CN=ExampleSrvCa/O=Example/C=FR
  ---
  No client certificate CA names sent
  ---
  SSL handshake has read 6410 bytes and written 934 bytes
  ---
  New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA256
  Server public key is 4096 bit
  Secure Renegotiation IS supported
  Compression: NONE
  Expansion: NONE
  SSL-Session:
      Protocol  : TLSv1.2
      Cipher    : AES256-SHA256
      Session-ID: ABC...
      Session-ID-ctx:
      Master-Key: DEF...
      Key-Arg   : None
      PSK identity: None
      PSK identity hint: None
      SRP username: None
      Start Time: 1391654253
      Timeout   : 300 (sec)
      Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
  ```
- Running `openssl verify -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CN=ldap.example.com_O=Example_C=FR.crt` says certificate is OK

Comment: Found some `LDAPTrustedGlobalCert` directives into various VirtualHost files (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/`) but outside `<VirtualHost>`. Theses where pointing to an old self-signed certificate for the same FQDN (legacy tests). After cleaning the entire Apache config, both SSL and TLS LDAP authentication worked just fine (no need of any `LDAPTrustedGlobalCert` anywhere...)

Answer (score 4):

Well, first let's confirm that the certificate trust is actually the problem.  Does it work with `LDAPVerifyServerCert Off`?

Also, let's confirm that the LDAP service is talking with a certificate that will work; connect to it:

```
openssl s_client -connect ldap.example.com:636 -showcerts
```

If it's just sending its host certificate and not the intermediate or root certificates that signed it, you'll need to be trusting the intermediate certificate explicitly with Apache.

Grab the host cert that was output during that `s_client` connection and write it to a file, then verify that the signature is good:

```
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt received-cert.crt
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify that it is working if I use `LDAPVerifyServerCert Off`. `openssl s_client ... -showcerts` send every certificates first the LDAP server, then each intermediate CA then the root CA. `openssl verify -CAfile` says LDAP server certificate (first one received) is OK (original post edited to adds theses infos).